# Windows 10 slow boot nvidia gtx 980

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently updated my graphics card to a EVGA GTX 980 on my windows 10 machine. the problem is that with the card in the system, windows 10 takes a VERY long time to boot, almost 45 mins to get to the login screen. Once logged in the system is SO sluggish that it is unusable. Here are a few things ive tried and it seems the the problem seems to be windows 10.

system info:

Gigabyte P55A-UD4P motherboard
core i7 SOMETHING CPU
32GB of ram
240GB SSD boot drive (windows 10)
EVGA GTX 980 4GB

I pulled the GTX card out and put in my old radeon 5770 and bam! system booted up normally (fast) once i was back in the desktop i clean uninstalled any amd drivers to make sure its not a driver issue. pulled the radeon card and put back the gtx and got the same slow boot. i even tried safe boot and the same issue. also tried to boot from recovery usb and same slow issue.
now i have other OS's and the card works and boots just fine. Seems to be a windows 10 problem here. just for kicks i put in there an old nvidia gt440 and it booted normally. I didnt have this issue with windows 7 when i had the old gt440 (system was updated to 10 from 7) i also removed any traces of nvidia drivers as well.

any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any errors in the log files (eventviewer!)

Comment: Check the SATA power cable. I installed a new drive, knocked the connector for my boot SSD and it was unbearably slow. Turns out it was because the power wasn't seated right and the SSD was barely scraping through boot. Reseat the connector and all was well.

Comment: install the WPT (part of the Windows SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), and run the xbootmgr command from here: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE. zip the ETL, upload the zip and post a share link here

Comment: thank you! i did reseat the connectors when i was swapping cards. will try the WPT.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download their new NVIDIA GeForce Experience to your windows10 install again. Then run the updates again.

Comment: thank you for the response! i did when i was able to boot with the older gt440. then when i put the gtx980 back in the system i had the same super slow boot and machine becomes unusable.